# Single cell with multiple collectionview in a viewcontroller

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I want to use a same cell in another collectionView in a same ViewController. What I have tried is, design the cell with objects in a collectionView and I have used the same name of collectionView cell for another collectionView cell with different identifier. While during the cell for rowAtIndexPath, I have separated the collectionView with tag. But I got nil for the objects for eg.cell.thumbNailImageView.

Comment: Show your code!

Comment: Create a custom UICollectionViewCell class.